# How should my players realize they misidentified an item?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e

One of my players critically failed an [Identify Magic](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=24) roll on a [Pendant of the Occult](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=450), a magic item which can be used to cast [Guidance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=142) on a target. Since he misidentified it, I told him it can be used on a target to give a -1 status penalty to their next attack roll, Perception check, saving throw, or skill check (basically reverse-[Guidance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=142)).

I immediately realized I didn't make the effect obvious enough, so the players probably won't notice that the Pendant is having the opposite effect unless I add some sort of descriptive flourish to make the effect blatant.

Is there any guidance in the rules as to how (or when) PCs should realize that they misidentified a magic item? Or is it up to the GM to provide descriptions and hints as necessary, if the GM wants them to realize their mistake?

Comment: So is this a cursed item?

Comment: Are the players using the item often enough for this to actually come up in play?

Comment: @RevenantBacon No, it's a regular Pendant of the Occult. But since I told them it will impose a -1 penalty, they will use it on enemies. But really it will cast the Guidance spell on the enemies, as the Pendant of the Occult does.

Comment: @Fering They just got the item, so I'm not sure how often they'll use it. +1/-1 is obviously not a huge deal, anyway. My question is mostly asking if there is any particular rules guidance about PCs realizing they misidentified, or if it's up to the GM to give them hints that they misidentified. I edited my question to hopefully make things clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PCs misidentify an item when they critically fail an Identify Magic task (Core Rules, 238). Although they are allowed to retry on a failure, there is no explicit rule on retrying on a critical failure.

In-fiction it doesn't make much sense to re-identify the item, because the PC already believes they know what it is. Unless they are presented with some clear evidence that their belief is incorrect there is no reason to allow another try at identifying it. Since the effects of the item are so small, that may never happen.

As the GM you can provide the PCs reasons to attempt this check again. Perhaps some NPCs correctly identify it and treat it with disdain, the PCs attempt to sell it and the appraiser won't take it, etc.

Outside of storytelling, each PC can make their own check to identify the item. Unless the entire party critically fails on the task, it seems unlikely everyone will misidentify the item. Additionally, someone with the Recognize Spell skill feat (pg.265) who is trained in Occult can use their reaction to identify the spell as it occurs.

Comment: Your last sentence is incorrect. Any such character that spends their Reaction to identify the spell will automatically succeed.

Comment: Moreover, you automatically identify spells that you have in your repertoire or prepared, even without Recognize Spell, so if *anyone* in the party has *guidance* prepared or known... they know it was cast.

Answer (score 5):

### A simple solution

Providing an obvious effect resolves your situation. Have one of the PC's recognize Guidance (an NPC can also accomplish this if none of them know the spell) when the item is used. "The specifics of that effect seem familiar to you. You can use a Recall Knowledge (Occultism, Nature, or Religion) now or after this combat if you'd like to know more" or "The crotchety old cleric exclaims 'Stop helping the enemy, you fool!'".

More generally, accidentally casting a buff on an enemy (or debuff on an ally) can have visual cues "The bandit's blade seems like it's about to swerve wide, but magic swirls around his wrist causing it to land". This can be done even if the +1 didn't make the difference, at your discretion.